# couldn't find launch groovy command on terminal after installing it with gvm

Tags: groovy, gvm

I just installed groovy with gvm

```
gvm install groovy
```

and then restarted the terminal
I had a grails installation before that using gvm and I get the grails version when I issue the command

```
gvm current
```

Now I can't run groovy or groovyconsole from terminal. What am I missing?

Comment: looks `gvm l groovy` ok?

Comment: `gvm l groovy` shows that version 2.4.1 is installed. But how do I launch it?

Comment: what returns `which groovy` in a new terminal session?

Comment: not even `groovy not found`?  well then you should check your ~/.gvm/groovy and see if there is a current directory.  also make sure, that you have set the groovy version to current (annotated with a `*` in the list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not set `current` (should get asked on installation).  Check what version is installed (`gvm ls groovy`).  Installed versions have `*` set.  The current is marked with an `>`.  Set the current manually:

```
gvm d groovy <version>
```